# Trouble with writing to a .txt file in a function

Tags: file, text, printf

I am trying to replace my printf statements with a fprintf statement. But when i go to implement into one of my function, it gives me a when i call my function.

> error: expected expression before 'FILE'|

here is my code:

> profit+= 
>   Raffle(raffle_person,raffle_ticket,number_raffle_items,raffle_price,&num_raffle_ticket,
>   FILE * ofp);

then my function declarations and my function:

> float Raffle (int person, int amt_raffle_tickets, int
>   num_raffle_prize,float price_of_raffle_ticket, int *
>   num_raffle_ticket, FILE * ofp){

my project is due today, and this is the LAST thing...and of course... ill have a problem. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the code you wrote. How many of the parameters you're passing have the **variable type** in front of them, and which **one** of them is indicated in your error message?

```
profit += Raffle(raffle_person, 
                 raffle_ticket,
                 number_raffle_items,
                 raffle_price,
                 &num_raffle_ticket, 
                 FILE * ofp);
```

Error messages contain actual words, and you should learn to **read them**; they almost always have meaningful information in them. :-)

Comment: hahah oh my... wow i feel like an idiot. cant wait to get this class done hahah!